# Upload file, which has more size, throwing out of memory exception using ajax and MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload a file using ajax and MVC, this code is working fine for small files, but if size is exceed, it is throwing out of memory exception 
My JQuery code

```
$("#btn-upload-package").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($("#frm-single-migrate").validationEngine("validate") == true) {

    var fileUpload = $("#frm_file_upload").get(0);
    var files = fileUpload.files;

    var fileData = new FormData();
    fileData.append(files[0].name, files[0]);
    fileData.append('SourceName', $('#txt_source_package').val());

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("UploadSourceAndVerify", "Home")',
      data: fileData,
      async:true,
      contentType: false, 
      processData: false, 
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.IsError) {
          ShowAlert('Error..!', data.Error);
        }
        else {
          ShowAlert('Success', "File has been uploaded successfully");
        }
      },
      error: function (data) {
        alert("Please contact your administrator");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

MVC code is like this:

```
 public ActionResult UploadSourceAndVerify()
    {
        string SourcePackageName = Request.Form["SourceName"];
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
        string fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), file.FileName);  
        file.SaveAs(fname);

        return Json(JsonViewModel);
    }
```

When I am trying to get Request.Files[0], it is throwing memory out of exception

Please let me know any way is there to upload large files, I think i have done everything proper in configuration files

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It is 513MB, But in future it could be up to 2GB

Comment: Please don't put a screen shot of you code. Put that actual code into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your `web.config` file and increase the max allowed file size, like this

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <!-- This will handle requests up to 1024MB (1GB) -->
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" timeout="3600" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

<!-- IIS Specific Targeting (noted by the system.webServer section) -->
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <!-- This will handle requests up to 1024MB (1GB) -->
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

But it is also possible that the target server simply does not have enough resources to process that large file and runs out of RAM. If that is the case, then web.config will not help you as the machine is too weak to process large files. Maybe you will have to buy more RAM? :)

Comment: Still am facing the same issue , I have a 4GB RAM in my machine :( , Thank you for your suggestion, Please let me know any other possibility

Comment: If the target machine is the same as the one where you are developing, than 4GB RAM is probably not enough. The development IDE can consume around 1GB, the OS itself maybe the same, then you have bunch of various programes, web browsers etc... The file processing takes same RAM too. Check the memory consumption during + after upload in the Task Manager or do some profiling in IDE

Comment: Ok thank you, I have checked and you are right, machine almost using 80 % memory and I will try with an upgraded machine

Answer (score 0):

As told @David Votrubec , It was an issue with machine , with lack of enough memory. Thank you every one for every one for helpful suggestions